# TMS-90035: Invalid Signature

Tags: ionic, xcode, ionic3, ionic-framework

Recibo el siguiente error por parte de Apple al intentar distribuir la app, ya he subido versiones anteriores de la app sin embargo ahora recibo este error.

Estoy usando versión de ionic 3.

> TMS-90035: Invalid Signature - A sealed resource is missing or
>   invalid. The file at path .. is not properly signed.
>   Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution
>   certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate.
>   Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the
>   target level (which override any values at the project level) etc...

- He generado nuevamente los certificados.
- He generado nuevamente la plataforma.

Alguno sabe alguna solución para este problema, al validar la aplicación todo es correcto pero en el procesamiento en App Store Connect falla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la siguiente solución que me funciono en mi caso particular.

El error se debe a un asset que tiene como nombre un carácter especial. Para solucionarlo se realizo lo siguiente:

Ir a la carpeta raíz de proyecto en ionic por la terminal y ejecutar el siguiente comando

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '*[! -~]*'
```

Con este comando aparecen todos los archivos que tenga caracteres especiales en el nombre. Puede eliminar el archivo o simplemente remover el carácter especial y ya se puede distribuir.